# Instantiation of the statement : (x)Px ∨ (x)Qx

Tags: predicate-logic

1.(x)Px ∨ (x)Qx

I am currently reading a logic book by Patrick J. Hurley, and in the book the author says that we can't universally instantiate a statement like statement 1. Specifically, he says that universal instantiation must be applied only to whole lines but he never explains why universal instantiation is applicable only to whole lines.

I don't know why it might be wrong to instantiate statement 1 at just one step. For example, what is wrong with using John as our instance and then saying that either John has the property P or John has the property Q?

Comment: Note your case 1 proposition is a disjunction of 2 universals. If universal instantiation (UI) is not applied to the whole line then it could simply possibly result in a situation after applying UI you arrive at "*either John is P or Paul is Q*" which is distorted semantically from the original...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does seem to be valid to do it to each sub-expression at once. But that's just not the way universal instantiation works, formally. There's no particular reason it couldn't work that way, since it would still be valid if it was - it just is defined not to. So if you are following the rules of the deductive system strictly, you can't do it that way.

Instead you would assume (x)Px and derive P(John) so you get (x)Px -> P(John), then assume (x)Qx and derive Q(John) so you get (x)Qx -> Q(John), then you can use a constructive dilemma to infer P(John) v Q(John).